# Match each character in a character-combination, plus the combination value itself, in Bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression

When practicing regex in Bash I tried to match the entire set/search-pattern inside the brackets.

Instead, I matched just each single character in them.

For example, with

```
cd
touch a.c a.h a.o a.cho
ls *.[cho]
```

The `ls` matched:

```
a.c
a.h
a.o
```

but it didn't match the entire set as in `a.cho`.

Why didn't I match the entire set as well and how is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using regular expressions here, but filename globbing patterns.

The `[...]` will only ever match a single character (this happens to be the same between filename globbing patterns and regular expressions), which is why it does not match the three characters `cho` (`[cho]` means "one of `c`, `h` and `o`").

To match all names starting with `a.` use `a.*`.

To match all names starting with `a.` and then directly afterwards ending in either `c`, `h`, `o` or `cho`, first set the `extglob` shell option with `shopt -s extglob` and use `a.@([cho]|cho)`.

A brace expansion like `a.{c,h,o,cho}` would generate the filenames on the command line, but gives no guarantee that those files actually exists.

Comment: Oh crap, why do I sometimes call globbing regex. I must stop this forever. But can't we philosophize and say it is a "type" of regex just like JavaScript has it's "type of regex"? I know it's unorthodox, but is it enough false?...

Comment: Can we match all four endings in Bash globbing in one pattern?

Comment: @user9303970 See updated answer. Sorry for mentioning the `+(...)` pattern before. I rarely use the extended globbing patterns, so I had to do some testing. `@(...)` is what you may want to use.

Comment: If you want to match anything that has at least one of those characters after the final dot, use `*.+([cho])` (with extglob). That would match any and all of `a.c`, `a.h`, `a.ch`, `a.cho` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) which is *not* a pattern, but a list of strings

```
ls *.{c,h,o,cho}
```

The shell expands that *before* the ls command is executed to

```
ls *.c *.h *.o *.cho
```

Since brace expansion occurs before filename expansion, we can put the glob pattern inside the braces

```
ls *.{[cho],cho}
```